# Error after installing and including npm module into Meteor project

Tags: javascript, meteor, npm

I have a meteor project (latest version of Meteor).

```
meteor npm install --save name_of_package
```

This package is client side so I created a file inside my /client folder named mypackage.js ... inside I included the node package with:

```
import name_of_package from 'name_of_package';
```

Meteor will start but when I attempt to connect I am getting the following error:

```
graceful-fs.js:157 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

Line 156-158 code-block of graceful-fs.js :

```
var fs$ReadStream = fs.ReadStream
ReadStream.prototype = Object.create(fs$ReadStream.prototype)
ReadStream.prototype.open = ReadStream$open
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Not sure what I am missing here.

Thanks!

Comment: fs.ReadStream is the node filesystem wrapper. Not sure why it is unable to communicate with this.

Answer (score 0):

May be a naming conflict. Did you perhaps install `fs-extra`? Have a look at this: [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined Meteor-File Package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49392058/9518096)