# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined Meteor-File Package

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, fs

I have a problem when using this documentation: https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/wiki/Image-Processing. This doc guides about create thumbnail images for pakage [Meteor-File](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files)

I installed all need package like the guiding, but when I run code, it had a problem:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at patch (modules.js?hash=b849b729a9c5ee343b208254dca34d866ee59991:19084)
    at graceful-fs.js (modules.js?hash=b849b729a9c5ee343b208254dca34d866ee59991:18945)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d188e038b75ecd27ed2469a52b269e38fb62:343)
    at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d188e038b75ecd27ed2469a52b269e38fb62:238)
    at index.js (modules.js?hash=b849b729a9c5ee343b208254dca34d866ee59991:16785)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d188e038b75ecd27ed2469a52b269e38fb62:343)
    at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d188e038b75ecd27ed2469a52b269e38fb62:238)
    at index.js (modules.js?hash=b849b729a9c5ee343b208254dca34d866ee59991:16624)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d188e038b75ecd27ed2469a52b269e38fb62:343)
    at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d188e038b75ecd27ed2469a52b269e38fb62:238)
```

I follow the trace, and found the prototype in here:

```
  var fs$ReadStream = fs.ReadStream                                                                                 
  ReadStream.prototype = Object.create(fs$ReadStream.prototype)                                                       
  ReadStream.prototype.open = ReadStream$open
```

'fs' lib is using in here:

```
import fs from 'fs-extra';
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try with something like this ?

```
var fs$ReadStream = fs.ReadStream                                                                                 
fs.ReadStream.prototype = Object.create(fs$ReadStream.prototype)                                                       
fs.ReadStream.prototype.open = ReadStream$open
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this problem by simply using the built-in node `fs` module instead of `fs-extra`. Have not had any problems so far.

Answer (score 0):

'fs' lib is available in server side. so just wrap these code in block:

```
if (Meteor.isServer()){
   //use fs lib
}
```

or switch code file to server 's folder.
It will work fine!